# Get details about the Connected WiFi Network

Tags: networking, wireless, debian

I'm trying to get the details of the WiFi network that I've connected to. I have already tried ***iwlist wlan0 scan*** which give the details of the connected network as well as all the available networks too. And it also take nearly 5 seconds to get the data in the terminal. I also tried ***iw dev wlan0 link*** which gives the exact details that I required but it lacks to provide the signal quality (in percentage). So is there any command which would give the details of the wifi network like **Essid Name, Address, Signal Quality, Signal Strength(RSSI)**.

**Commands I've tried:**

***sudo iwlist wlan0 scan***,
the output is

```
          wlan0     Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: 30:5A:3A:9B:4A:A2
                    Channel:6
                    Frequency:2.437 GHz (Channel 6)
                    Quality=56/70  Signal level=-54 dBm 
                    Encryption key:off
                    ESSID:"Innova1"
                    Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=000000012e7f4a65
                    Extra: Last beacon: 200ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 0007496E6E6F766131
                    IE: Unknown: 010482848B96
                    IE: Unknown: 030106
                    IE: Unknown: 072A494E000101100201100301100401100501100601100701100801100901100A01100B01100C01100D0110
                    IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                    IE: Unknown: 32080C1218243048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1A2C0103FF00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1606000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101810003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00**
```

Another Command is ***sudo iw dev wlan0 link***,

the output is 
**

```
Connected to 30:5a:3a:9b:4a:a2 (on wlan0)
SSID: Innova1
freq: 2437
RX: 18079342 bytes (101462 packets)
TX: 2279813 bytes (17536 packets)
signal: -58 dBm
tx bitrate: 43.3 MBit/s MCS 4 short GI
bss flags:  short-preamble short-slot-time
dtim period:    2
beacon int: 100**
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try `nmcli d wifi` which does not require `sudo` privilege. This gives some of the information you want, and lists all networks, but the connected one has an asterisk so you can use `grep` to get only the headers and the line you want like so:

```
$ nmcli d wifi | grep ^\*
*  SSID                    MODE   CHAN  RATE       SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY         
*  SKY5952D                Infra  11    54 Mbit/s  73      ▂▄▆_  WPA2
```